# Hey has invalid arguments

Tags: c#, visual-c#-express-2010

I am doing some homework and I got stuck, almost everything seems to be working right except 2 lines at the end, I have switched stuff around a bunch and i just cant seem to get it right.

The homework question is

> Design a program that asks the user to enter a string and then converts that string to Morse code. Morse code is a code where each letter of the English alphabet, each digit, and various punctuation characters are represented by a series of dots and dashes. Table 8-7shows part of the code.

The dictionary entry I have as far as I can tell should convert all the characters correctly, but I cannot get the program to even run because of the invalid arguments I guess I have at the end, a copy of my code is below, if anyone could help I would really appreciate it. I will comment where it is showing the invalid arguments. Any tips or pushes in the right direction would be greatly appreciated

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MorseCode
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void convertbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string input = userinput.Text.Trim();
        outputlabel.Text = mcodeconv(input);
    }
    private string mcodeconv(string input)
    {
        string codeConvert = string.Empty;
        Dictionary<string, string> newmorse = new Dictionary<string, string>        ();
        {
            newmorse.Add(" " , "space");
            newmorse.Add("," , "--..--");
            newmorse.Add("." , ".-.-.-");
            newmorse.Add("?" , "..--..");
            newmorse.Add("0" , "-----");
            newmorse.Add("1" , ".----");
            newmorse.Add("2" , "..---");
            newmorse.Add("3" , "...--");
            newmorse.Add("4" , "....-");
            newmorse.Add("5" , ".....");
            newmorse.Add("6" , "-....");
            newmorse.Add("7" , "--...");
            newmorse.Add("8" , "---..");
            newmorse.Add("9" , "----.");
            newmorse.Add("A" , ".-");
            newmorse.Add("B" , "-...");
            newmorse.Add("C" , "-.-.");
            newmorse.Add("D" , "-..");
            newmorse.Add("E" , ".");
            newmorse.Add("F" , "..-.");
            newmorse.Add("G" , "--.");
            newmorse.Add("H" , "....");
            newmorse.Add("I" , "..");
            newmorse.Add("J" , ".---");
            newmorse.Add("K" , "-.-");
            newmorse.Add("L" , ".-..");
            newmorse.Add("M" , "- --");
            newmorse.Add("N" , "-.");
            newmorse.Add("O" , "---");
            newmorse.Add("P" , ".--.");
            newmorse.Add("Q" , "--.-");
            newmorse.Add("R" , ".-.");
            newmorse.Add("S" , "…");
            newmorse.Add("T" , "-");
            newmorse.Add("U" , "..-");
            newmorse.Add("V" , "...-");
            newmorse.Add("W" , ".--");
            newmorse.Add("X" , "-..-");
            newmorse.Add("Y" , "-.--");
            newmorse.Add("Z" , "--..");
            KeyValuePair<string, string> newvalue = new KeyValuePair<string,     string>();
        };
        char newChar;
        foreach (char ex in input)
        {
            newChar = char.ToUpper(ex);
            if(newmorse.ContainsKey(newChar))  //it throws the error here
            {
                codeConvert += newmorse[newChar]; //it throws the error here
            }
            else
            {
                codeConvert += ex;
            }
        }
        return codeConvert;
    }
    private void exitbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Your `newmorse` dictionary should be a `Dictionary<char, string>`. Then, for each of the keys, surround with single quotes: `newmorse.Add('A', ...); newmorse.Add('B', ...);`. You are currently trying to lookup a character in a dictionary whose keys are strings. You have to have matching datatypes.

Comment: Cory's comment and Niyoko's answer are correct. You're comparing string to char which doesn't work. Either make the char as string or make the dictionary's key as char.

Answer (score 4):

You should use  `Dictionary<char, string>` here and change your first argument in the `.Add` call into single quote. Your error is because you lookup `Dictionary` with `string` keys using `char` argument.

For example:

```
Dictionary<char, string> newmorse = new Dictionary<char, string>();

newmorse.Add(' ' , "space");
newmorse.Add(',' , "--..--");
newmorse.Add('.' , ".-.-.-");
newmorse.Add('?' , "..--..");

// etc
```